# Encoding odd HTML entities '&lstroke;'

Tags: php, html, xml, character-encoding, html-entities

I have problems with some odd HTML entities that comes from a XML file that I have to parse in PHP 5.6.

Some of the HTML entities are:

```
&lstroke;
n&acute;
a&hook;
e&hook;
```

The XML comes from CAB Abstracts (http://www.cabi.org/publishing-products/online-information-resources/cab-abstracts/) and its header is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

However, I have tried several encoding systems without success. Also, I have tried using them directly in HTML files, writing them from PHP 5.6 using html_entity_decode like this:

```
$strings = array('&Sacute;wia&hook;tek', 'Kie&lstroke;kiewicz', 'Zagdan&acute;ska', 'Mie&hook;tkiewski');

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    foreach (array(
            'ISO-8859-1', 'ISO-8859-5', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-8',
            'cp866', 'cp1251', 'cp1252', 'KOI8-R', 'BIG5', 'GB2312',
            'BIG5-HKSCS', 'Shift_JIS', 'EUC-JP', 'MacRoman', '') as $l) {
        print $l . ' ==> ';
        print html_entity_decode($s, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1 | ENT_XHTML | ENT_HTML5, $l) . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Nothing works!!

I would like to avoid any kind of solution that include parsing the XML file replacing these entities by the right UTF-8 character. I can not foreseen when odd HTML entities like these will be included and the files are relatively big.

The string should look like these:

```
Świątek
Kiełkiewicz
Zagdańska 
Miętkiewski
```

So, the question is:

How can I decode this odd HTML entities to UTF-8 in PHP?

Comment: Any information on where this XML originated?

Comment: How do you expect to both *avoid any kind of solution that include parsing the XML file replacing these entities by the right UTF-8 character*  yet still *decode this odd HTML entities to UTF-8 in PHP*?  Are you saying that you're ok with programmatically replacing strings such as `e&hook;` with its proper UTF-8 representation as long as it's done dynamically via PHP?

Comment: I'm saying that I don't want to parse the XML from my code using my own functions to replace the odd html entities. I would like to use any PHP internal function or library that could offer a long-term solution.

Comment: You should provide the XML in question *with* your question because some things tend to be here slightly off-track. For example from the declaration you show of that XML this is indeed an XML document. But when you come to the point you've got a problem with you talk about *HTML* entities. So now it's not clear whether you talk about HTML embedded into XML, XHTML or XML. I don't know cabi.org so I couldn't find the XML there you're asking about. So to make your question more complete and more clear, please add some more information and make the example self-containing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm afraid that my problem have to be solve with the solution that I was trying to avoid. The people from the database that produce the XML accept that these are typographic errors. So, I will have to use @Michas solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks this is an **own standard** to encode Polish letters. There would be no build in function. The official diacritic for *Ą*, *ą*, *Ę* and *ę* is known as ogonek (both in Polish and English). The `&acute;` is for the spacing variant, there should be used the combining one in this context.

I think the best option is to encode the output in UTF-8 and use `strtr()` for all these special characters. You don't have to parse XML, You can treat it as plain text.

Comment: Won't work for CDATA sections in the XML (if the question is about XML and not CDATA sections containing HTML within XML).

Comment: No, it won't. strtr() has no idea about the XML structure.

Answer (score 0):

Own standard, as @Michas said.

By the way, &lstrok; (not &lstroke;, it's common mistake) etc. For anyone:

```
char. - (like) - entity - UTF-8 hex
ą - (a) - &aogon; - C4,85
Ą - (A) - &Aogon; - C4,84
ć - (c) - &cacute; - C4,87
Ć - (C) - &Cacute; - C4,86
ę - (e) - &eogon; - C4,99
Ę - (E) - &Eogon; - C4,98
ł - (l) - &lstrok; - C5,82
Ł - (L) - &Lstrok; - C5,81
ń - (n) - &nacute; - C5,84
Ń - (N) - &Nacute; - C5,83
ó - (o) - &oacute; - C3,B3
Ó - (O) - &Oacute; - C3,93
ś - (s) - &sacute; - C5,9B
Ś - (S) - &Sacute; - C5,9A
ż - (z) - &zdot; - C5,BC
Ż - (Z) - &Zdot; - C5,BB
ź - (z) - &zacute; - C5,BA
Ź - (Z) - &Zacute; - C5,B9
```

Although, they can be still not recognized by f.e. mb_convert_encoding() (only &oacute;, &Oacute; are OK.):

```
echo mb_convert_encoding("ąć-ęł-ńóś-źż ĄĆ-ĘŁ-ŃÓŚ-ŹŻ", 'HTML', 'UTF-8');
// "&#261;&#263;-&#281;&#322;-&#324;&oacute;&#347;-&#378;&#380; &#260;&#262;-&#280;&#321;-&#323;&Oacute;&#346;-&#377;&#379;"
echo mb_convert_encoding("&aogon;&cacute;-&eogon;&lstrok;-&nacute;"
."&oacute;&sacute;-&zacute;&zdot; &Aogon;&Cacute;-&Eogon;"
."&Lstrok;-&Nacute;&Oacute;&Sacute;-&Zacute;&Zdot;", 'UTF-8', 'HTML')
// "&aogon;&cacute;-&eogon;&lstrok;-&nacute;\xC3\xB3&sacute;-&zacute;&zdot; &Aogon;&Cacute;-&Eogon;&Lstrok;-&Nacute;\xC3\x93&Sacute;-&Zacute;&Zdot;"
```

Is "any PHP internal function or library that could offer a long-term solution"? Maybe no...

Polish entities - see

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references
- https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin_extended_a.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin1_supplement.asp